# Creating embedded entities with the datastore command line tool

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use the Google cloud datastore command line interface to create arrays of embedded entities.  I've figured out how to create an embedded entity value as follows:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "age": {
            "integerValue": "5"
        },
        "height": {
            "integerValue": "6"
        }
    }
}
```

and how to create an array value as follows:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "stringValue": "one"
        },
        {
            "stringValue": "two"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I haven't figured out how to add an embedded value to an array.  For example:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "stringValue": "one"
        },
        {
            "stringValue": "two"
        },
        {
            "embeddedEntityValue": {
                "properties": {
                    "age": {
                        "integerValue": "5"
                    },
                    "height": {
                        "integerValue": "6"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

gives the error:
"One or more values in this array doesn't look right. If you include values, make sure they are Datastore array values in JSON format."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `embeddedEntityValue` should be changed to `entityValue`. Below is an example that shows an Array field with two embedded entities:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "entityValue": {
        "properties": {
          "areaCode": {
            "stringValue": "40"
          },
          "countryCode": {
            "stringValue": "91"
          },
          "subscriberNumber": {
            "stringValue": "2722 5858"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "entityValue": {
        "properties": {
          "countryCode": {
            "stringValue": "91"
          },
          "subscriberNumber": {
            "stringValue": "6666 0000"
          },
          "areaCode": {
            "stringValue": "80"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```