# Creating and copying multilevel embedded entity using Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Google Cloud Platform and trying to do a POC for one of the project 
 I have two queries -

**Consider the following entity structure :**

**1. Trying to create using Google data store (console)   -**

- **Entity-name : Client**
- **Namespace : foo**

  {
      "_id" : "number",
      "name" : "string",
      "location" : "string",
      "project-config" :
       {
              "_id": "string",
              "description" :"string",
              **"checklist" : 
              {
                  "name" : "string",
                  "items" : 
                  {
                      "Item-1" : "string",
                      "Item-2" : "Integer",
                      "Item-3" : "Date",
                      "Item-n" : "type",
                      "custom-added" :"type"
                  }**
              }
          }
      }

I was able to create one level embedded entity till "**project-config**" . However unable to figure out how to create another level of embedded entity(**checklist**) within project-config.

I referred [Creating embedded entities with the datastore command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739668/creating-embedded-entities-with-the-datastore-command-line-tool) but it explains more on creating embedded value not nested embedded entity.

Second problem is ,I want to create a copy of the parent entity for multi-tenancy.  I referred documentation from Google but it was not clear enough on how to actually create a copy https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/multitenancy

Answer (score 0):

Your first question was [answered in a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059355/saving-json-as-a-value-inside-embedded-entities-in-cloud-datastore) - Datastore does not support this, you would need to convert the JSON format to a String first.

For your second issue, multitenancy in Datastore is achieved by using different namespaces. The documentation has examples of implementing multitenancy in [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/multitenancy/multitenancy#Python_Using_namespaces_with_the_Datastore), [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Java_Using_namespaces_with_the_Datastore) and [Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/multitenancy/multitenancy#Go_Using_namespaces_with_the_Datastore)